# Translating PostGIS query to Django QuerySet (geoDjango postgis)

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to figure out how to translate a PostGIS query to GeoDjango:

```
def my_view(request, tempounix):
    conn.execute('SELECT ST_X(geom) as x, ST_Y(geom) AS y, accuracy, altitude, speed, tempounix '
        'FROM authapp_posizione '
        'ORDER BY tempounix DESC LIMIT 1;')

    x, y, accuracy, altitude, speed, timestamp = c.fetchone()

    data = {
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [x, y],
             },
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                 "accuracy": accuracy,
                 "altitude": altitude,
                 "speed": speed,
                 "tempounix": tempounix,
             },  
        }
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: This doesn't look like you have attempted to use Django's ORM, which (usually) removes the need to write raw SQL. See documentation here for GeoDjango: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/

Comment: i saw the docs but i not find anything useful. raw query is the unique way that i found to do this type of query. For that i ask!

Comment: What error are you getting? Post the complete stack trace, if possible

Comment: type error invalid date cause the value is stored in db not like a string but a timestamp

Comment: so i need to translate this custom query with the django orm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use Django's QuerySets and Django's ORM you will need to define [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/) and use them:

```
# models.py:
class Position(models.Model):
    geom = models.PointField(...)
    accuracy = models.IntegerField()
    altitude = models.IntegerField()
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

And now:

```
 p = Position.objects.order_by("-created_at").first()
 if p:
     print(p.created_at, p.geom.coordinates, p.altitude)
```